# LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<T> in android 2.1

Tags: android, sqlite, android-loadermanager

I am a newbie to Android application development. I am reading the [ToDo](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#loader_loader) tutorial. This article is based on android SDK version 3.0 and upper, but I am using sdk 2.1, which does not contain 'LoaderManager' class. I want to know is there any alternative for that class in 2.1 sdk? Is it really needed ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the compatibility library to the project.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

and then

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
```